# Linux software for simulating electric circuits

Tags: linux, simulation, cad

I'm looking for Linux software to simulate electric circuits. Basically software which I can give a circuit and ask it for currents, voltages, graphs and so...

I'm using OrCAD on a windows virtual machine. There are some nice online utilities like [this one](http://www.partsim.com/). I'm looking for something similar to those but works natively on Linux and preferably is free (both meanings).

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Quite Universal Circuit Simulator](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/). It is a cross platform circuit analysis software and one of the best.

[image: QUCS]

Open source.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use 123d circuits. This circuit simulator can simulate many different circuits using breadboards and Arduino. It is not an application that you install it is a web service. I have used it and it seems to load pretty fast and it seems to be pretty smooth. The application is free and it can measure voltage but you have to add an object to your board. You can also design Printed Circuit Boards(PCBS) using this piece of software and it has a pretty good community.[image]

Comment: "*natively on Linux*"